# SQL (Presto): Return Date when Sum of x equals some threshold

Tags: sql, window-functions, presto, rank

I have a table the one below. I want to return the Date when the sum of Result not equal to 'na' is equal to 4

| Date | ID | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12-01-21 | a | Negative |
| 12-01-21 | b | Negative |
| 12-02-21 | b | Negative |
| 12-02-21 | c | na |
| 12-03-21 | d | Positive |

Desired output:

```
Date
2021-03-21
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?
I have an idea of some elements people use from quickly searching, such as some combination rank functions, inner queries, or WITH, but I do not know the structure or format in which to arrange.

For example, logically I was thinking, rank the table by date, when pull the Date when count(Date) = 4 ,but I'm not sure of the structure. I can come up with logic, it's the structure that is the hard part for me.

Thank you for your patience and time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SUM() OVER ()` window function along with a conditional such as

```sql
WITH tt AS
(
 SELECT t.*, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN Result!='na' THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS rnk
   FROM t
)
SELECT Date
  FROM tt
 WHERE rnk = 4
```

or `ROW_NUMBER()`

```sql
WITH tt AS
(
 SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS rnk
   FROM t
  WHERE Result!='na' 
)
SELECT Date
  FROM tt
 WHERE rnk = 4
```